# DVD/CD Drive no longer shows in Finder

Tags: finder, dvd

I tried to drag a DVD to  VLC app. Instead the entire DVD/CD drive just disappeared from Finder.  The drive is still there: I can play a DVD on it. But it does not show up in *Locations*.

**Update 6 months later**   I have tried two different external Cd/DVD drive's: both can play DVD/USB's but neither show up in Finder.

[image]

Note that it is enabled in the *Preferences:*

[image]

How can the DVD/CD drive be re-added to Finder?  I am on  Catalina with a Macbook Pro 2020.

**Update** Here are the *Sidebar* settings - showing that the *External disks* and *CDs, DVDs, Ipods* are enabled:

[image]

Comment: So the DVD doesn't show up in a Finder Window of "Stephen's MBP" or whatever your computer is called? It doesn't show up on the Desktop background? And it doesn't show up in the Sidebar? Also, note that the Sidebar pane of the Finder prefs also has settings for whether they show.

Comment: I also checked Sidebar settings and they are properly checked: will update the question. Everything you describe is the case and everything is checked/enabled in Settings. IThis all  went from working to not _without any settings changes_ when I installed _VLC_.  I have no idea why or how to reset this.

Comment: Just to be 100%: the DVD **does not** show up on your desktop?

Comment: @X_841 It _does_ show up on desktop: someone had suggested to drag from Desktop to Finder and _that works_

Comment: That was actually me trying to answer, yet in the comments it seemed like the DVD didn't show up on the desktop. Therefore I deleted it.

Comment: @X_841  Please make an answer - i would award

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to try is to test the problem in a new user account. If the DVDs show up in the Finder in a new user account, then you know the problem is *somewhere* in the original user account's Library: a corrupt or misconfigured preference, most likely.

If the problem still persists in a new user account, then you know it is at a System level: so either a bug in the OS itself, or some weird interaction with third-party software installed in `/Library`, or possibly a global preference that is similarly corrupt or misconfigured.

Going back to the user-level problem: if that is the case, then you need to 'hunt the thimble': find the file that's causing the problem. You can remove large swathes of files and folder from the User Library, test, and then restore them if nothing changes, or restore half of them if it does, and so on.

Likely candidates are *user*`/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist`, and `com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` in the same folder. You may need to look for other potentially relevant filenames.

Comment: I'll keep in mind and if it disappears again will delete `~/Library/Preferences/{com.apple.finder.plist, com.apple.sidebarlists.plist}`

Comment: Ok i'm going to delete those now just to see what happens.  No change in Finder: but I had already draged "Audio CD" and "Macintosh HD" into Favorites. Apparently the plists do not affect them?

Comment: Things may be cached, so you may have to relaunch the Finder (or indeed Log out and In again).

Comment: I'll restart Finder. Hold on..  OK yes now they show up in Locations!

Answer (score 2):

If you can see the DVD on your desktop, you can simply drag the DVD icon back into Finder.

You can enable showing DVDs on Desktop in Finder settings:
[image]

Then drag and drop your DVD back:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Someone had created an answer : "Drag the Audio CD from the Desktop to Finder".  I would like to award that: *please come back* ;)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I undeleted my question. Glad I could help ;)

Comment: I think you undeleted your _answer_ ;)  I upvoted but in the interim an answer precisely to the question was entered : so I did not actually award it. Thanks in any case: your answer is  simpler than the other one and represents another valid approach