# How to reset the Finder to its default settings?

Tags: finder

Can the *Finder* be reset to all original Default Settings?

Note there is a specific motivation:  I no longer can view external DVD/CD drives from *Finder* even though they both can play movies/music CD's: see [DVD/CD Drive no longer shows in Finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/392788/dvd-cd-drive-no-longer-shows-in-finder) .  Resetting to Defaults would just be another thing to try.

Answer (score 1):

To restore the Finder to its original state, you should enter this command.

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist; killall Finder
```